# Can you teleport 0 squares in a move action?

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation

There are many properties that trigger after teleportation in 4e. Is it possible to activate a teleport power and choose the distance teleported to be 0 squares? (effectively teleporting in place?)

Comment: I feel like invoking the *sack of rats* clause might be appropriate here.

Comment: Could you please explain the reason you'd want to do this? To break a grab?

Comment: @F.RandallFarmer best guess: he's trying to use something the triggers off a teleport, but wants to remain in current position.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: There are a number of things that trigger on teleport, but I may not want to give up my position. As a pixie, I'd quite like to be able to teleport "within the same square"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***No***

Though it is not explicitly called out, there is a preponderance of wording that suggests you must chose a destination space other than the current one.

Teleportation[[ddi]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=86)

> ... A teleportation power transports creatures or objects instantaneously from one location to another.

From one location to another. Strike 1 - Seems to exclude the same location - but depends on grammatical set theory. :-)

> ... ***Instantaneous***: Teleportation takes no time. The target disappears and immediately appears in the destination that the teleporting creature chooses. The movement is unhindered by intervening creatures, objects, or terrain.

Blocking isn't a problem.

> ... ***Destination Space:*** The destination of the teleportation must be an unoccupied space that is at least the same size as the target.

Strike 2 - The destination space is occupied - by you.

> ... *Immobilized or Restrained:* Being immobilized or restrained doesn’t prevent a target from teleporting. If a target teleports away from a physical restraint, a monster’s grasp, or some other immobilizing effect that is located in a specific space, the target is no longer immobilized or restrained. Otherwise, the target teleports but is still immobilized or restrained when it reaches the destination space.

Assuming `Teleport 0` is being used to escape restraint, this is Strike 3: You aren't teleporting away from restraint, so your are still restrained.

Despite all that, I imagine many DMs would house-rule otherwise, and I might be one of them.